# call/cc with Break procedure

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

```
(define RESUME "ANY THING...")
(define BREAK
  (lambda (msg)
    (call/cc
      (lambda (k)
        (set! RESUME k)
        ((lambda (x) x) msg)))))


(define addition
  (lambda (x y)
    (+ x (BREAK 7))))


(define main
  (lambda args
    (print (addition 8 5))
    (print (RESUME 1))))
```

Above code keep outputs 9s, like trapped in infinite loop, why is this?
from my understanding, (RESUME 1) should only be called once.

Invoke above program like below:
csi -ss break.scm

Comment: Every time you call `RESUME` its argument is returned from `BREAK` in the middle of `addition`. Since you call it after `addition` returns, it keeps looping back to that point.

Comment: `((lambda (x) x) msg)` is equivalent to `msg`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is creating a loop:

you save continuation like this:

```lisp
(define addition
  (lambda (x y)
    (+ x <SLOT>)))
```

and when you call `(RESUME 1)` it replaces the slot with 1 and continue execution of the code. Next line is this:

```lisp
(+ x 1)
```

And the rest of the code up the execution stack:

```
(print (addition 8 1)
(print (RESUME 1))
```

and when RESUME is called it jumps to the same place `<SLOT>` with `1`, so it creates infinite loop of 9, `(+ x 1) ==> (+ 8 1)`

You basically have implemented GOTO. This is a simplification of your code:

```lisp
(define GOTO "ANY THING...")
(define START (lambda ()
                (call/cc (lambda (k)
                           (set! GOTO k)))))

(define main
  (lambda args
    (START)
    (print "xx")
    (GOTO 'x))) ;; continuation needs argument
```